# iOS 7 UIDatePicker - missing white text?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uidatepicker

I'm just updating my application to use iOS 7. My plan is to set the background color in black with white text on a UIDatePicker. Is there a possible way I can set the color of the text on a UIDatePicker? If not, then it would be nice to have "setDatePickerViewStyle:UIDatePickerStyleLightContent" for UIDatePicker to be similar to the status bar style.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181225/customize-text-color-of-uidatepicker-for-ios7-just-like-mailbox-does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the styling guide, UIDatePickers cannot be styled:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW1